# Cellular-Lindelöf: a common generalization of the Lindelöf property and the CCC

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

All spaces are assumed to be Hausdorff. Recall that a *cellular family* in the space $X$ is a family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subspaces of $X$. The cellularity of $X$ ($c(X)$) is defined as the supremum of the cardinalities of the cellular families in $X$. CCC means that the cellularity is countable.

We say that a topological space $X$ is *cellular-Lindelöf* if for every cellular family $\mathcal{C}$ there is a Lindelöf subspace $Y$ of $X$ such that $U \cap Y \neq \emptyset$, for every $U \in \mathcal{C}$.

Clearly every Lindelöf space is cellular-Lindelöf and every CCC space is cellular-Lindelöf.

The cellular-Lindelöf property was introduced in our paper [On the cardinality of almost discretely Lindelöf spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00605-017-1112-4) with Bella, where we note that:

> > FACT: Cellular-Lindelöf first-countable spaces have cardinality at most $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Indeed, let $X$ be a first-countable cellular-Lindelöf space. Then $c(X) \leq \mathfrak{c}$ (this follows from Arhangel'skii's Theorem stating that every Lindelöf first-countable space has cardinality at most continuum). Combining that with the Hajnal-Juhasz inequality $|X| \leq 2^{\chi(X) \cdot c(X)}$ (where $\chi(X)$ denotes the character of $X$) we obtain that $|X| \leq 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

> > QUESTION: Let $X$ be a first-countable cellular-Lindelöf space. Is $|X| \leq \mathfrak{c}$?

A positive answer would lead to a common generalization of Arhangel'skii's Theorem and the Hajnal–Juhasz theorem stating that first-countable CCC spaces have cardinality at most continuum.

EDIT: (03/01/2024)

A partial answer can be found in a new paper with Bella: the answer is yes for normal spaces under $2^{<\mathfrak{c}}=\mathfrak{c}$.

*Bella, Angelo; Spadaro, Santi*, [**Cardinal invariants of cellular-Lindelöf spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13398-019-00660-1), Rev. R. Acad. Cienc. Exactas Fís. Nat., Ser. A Mat., RACSAM 113, No. 3, 2805-2811 (2019). [ZBL1468.54009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1468.54009).

Another partial answer can be found in work of Vladimir Tkachuk and Richard Wilson: the answer is yes for "cellular-compact" regular spaces in ZFC (you can guess the definition).

*Tkachuk, V. V.; Wilson, R. G.*, [**Cellular-compact spaces and their applications**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10474-019-00968-9), Acta Math. Hung. 159, No. 2, 674-688 (2019). [ZBL1449.54033](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1449.54033).

Their result was improved to cellular-compact Hausdorff spaces by Juhàsz, Soukup and Szentmiklòssy.

*Juhász, I.; Soukup, L.; Szentmiklóssy, Z.*, [**On cellular-compact spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10474-020-01035-4), Acta Math. Hung. 162, No. 2, 549-556 (2020). [ZBL1474.54031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1474.54031).